# Getting 'undefined' while fetching data from an URL using request module in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to simply use the request module and fetch the data from an API. It looks like no error is there even though I am getting 'undefined'. I am confused as it is because of any VS code settings or what. 
The editor I am using is - VS Code

```
Dependency list - 
{
"name": "weather-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "http": "0.0.0",
  "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
 }
```

Node and npm version -
C:\Users\lenovo>node -v
v10.16.0

C:\Users\lenovo>npm -v
6.9.1-next.0

```
const request = require('request')
const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5a6c29e0d9c879cef11d4d5de29d7d78/37.8267,-122.4233'
request({ url: url }, (error, response) => {
console.log(response)
})
```

The output I am getting - undefined.

The output I should get - JSON data from API request

Comment: did you try to print error

Comment: Hi Hemant - the error msg I got > Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: why do you have the code block inside double quotes? ".. I executed your code without any issues removing the ". Also the url should be in single line.

Comment: try putting folowing code at the top of js file
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0

Comment: I know it will be working fine most of your system but I am not getting where is the problem in my system. It should show me the right output. Do I need to add an extension or other things?

Answer (score 0):

I made a check on this and it works fine, please correct your code and try again

```js
const request = require('request')
const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5a6c29e0d9c879cef11d4d5de29d7d78/37.8267,-122.4233'
request({ url: url }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    console.log(response.body)
})
```

Comment: I am getting this error --     console.log(response.body)
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at Request.request [as _callback] (L:\Nodejs\NodeByAndrew\weather-app\app.js:7:26)
    at self.callback (L:\Nodejs\NodeByAndrew\weather-app\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)

Comment: Can you try to access this link https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5a6c29e0d9c879cef11d4d5de29d7d78/37.8267,-122.4233 in your browser? and does it return a json response?

Comment: I think there is some problem with my system settings. But I am afraid as I don't know how to check. I uninstalled node and reinstalled it evern though the same output.

Comment: How did you add the dependency list? Did you use npm init and then npm i request?

Comment: @Sujal I make a copy of package.json as above and run `npm install`

Comment: @thanhphan package.json is created when you use npm init. you don't copy the dependency. when you use npm install, the dependencies are added to the package.json

Comment: yup, In case of I don't want to install every module by `npm install <module> --save` so I copy package.json and just do `npm install` for faster

Comment: Yes i installed the modules by init methods